# 2005 Escape not starting

Tags: electrical, ford, starting

My 2005 Ford Escape won't start. 3 days ago, it was starting slow, now I get nothing, not even a sound. The battery is good, slightly less then a year old, all lights, windows, radio, etc work. Also, alternator is only 6 months old. Any advice would be appreciated. Could it be the starter?

Answer (score 1):

If you have electrical power but turning the key makes no sound, it could very well be the starter, especially since you said it was "starting slow" a few days ago.

Just to rule out the battery, take a multimeter and read your voltage. It should be around 12.4V.

One last thing you can do, give the starter a couple of whacks with a hammer and try to start right away. Sometimes it works.